# Where is PATH setup in Ubuntu 16.10 bash shell?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, bashrc, 16.10

I can't seem to determine where the bash `PATH` environment variable is getting setup on my fresh Ubuntu 16.10 install.

I have tried placing `echo $PATH` statements at the top of `~/.bashrc` and even `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Both echo statements get executed, so these files are loading properly, But, in both cases the `PATH` already contains the following:

```
/home/carl/bin:/home/carl/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

The first entries (`/home/carl/bin:/home/carl/.local/bin`) are what I'm trying to track down. I'm not really sure where any of the values are set since changing `/etc/environment` seems to have no effect.

The `PATH` is also setup when `/etc/profile` executes when using a login shell and is also unaffected by changes to `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Try `~/.profile`

Comment: It's not `~/.profile`. That isn't executed at all in an interactive non-login shell.

Comment: @CarlZulauf: In a desktop session it's sourced by the display manager (lightdm). So it's most certainly the file in question.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson you are correct. I didn't realize the desktop session itself loads `~/.profile` (which explains why `gnome-terminal` defaults to non-login shells) and requires logging out to take effect. Sorry @steeldriver for not understanding why you were correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the PATH was being persisted by the display manager loading `~/.profile`, (and `/etc/profile` and `/etc/environment`) when creating a desktop session. This means changes to those files aren't going to reflect in new bash sessions and require logging out to take effect.

Comment: To be more precise: `/etc/environment` is read by PAM and not sourced by anything. `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` are sourced by lightdm, but the former is not involved in setting environment variables by default.

Comment: Congrats on answering your own question. Don't forget to accept it as the solution in two days so others know it's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can find this out by run bash in in debug and login modes , its quite enlightening

```
/bin/bash -xl
```

There is quite lot of output but you should be able to see the whole chain of loading files and modifying $PATH.